# BeautifulSoup: Check if encoding warnings and tag that site to come back to later

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
error_urls = set()
correct_urls = set()
collected_text = []

page = 'https://abc.xyz/investor/static/pdf/2019Q4_alphabet_earnings_release.pdf'
headers = {'User-Agent': '''Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'''}
request = requests.get(page,headers = headers)
souped_page = bs4(request.content,'html.parser')
collected_text.append(souped_page.text())
correct_urls.add(page)
```

If I run this, the terminal prints "some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER." but the souped_page is created.

Sometimes, the url is not pdf, so I want to be able to check if this warning is created, to store the url elsewhere and not collect the text.

```
try:
    souped_page = bs4(request.content,'html.parser')
except encoding warning:
    error_urls.add(page)
```

Comment: Why use BeautifulSoup to parse a PDF file?

Comment: The url doesn't always say pdf, i am giving you a pathway to recreate it. If I collect a bunch of urls, I want to check to see if I get this warning and come back to it with a pdf reader.

Comment: That "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER" is a valid Unicode code, so you can test if it occurs in the text you just parsed.

Comment: How? souped_page.find("Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.")

Comment: Why ever would that entire string appear in the text? All it says is that unencoded characters are *already* replaced. Also (I didn't check the documentation) would `souped_page.find` also search in the *text*? You already have that text.

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand what you were suggesting.

Comment: The message says some characters **are** replaced. Therefore, the text that you are retrieving **contains** one or more of these characters. Therefore (it's still logical to me, sorry) you can search through that text and see if there are such characters in your text. If they are, the message was printed. QED.

Comment: Except I can't find any indication that the characters were replaced with anything in the documentation. - promptly vanishes in a puff of logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once the souped_page variable is created, it will print the log warning and the souped_page.contains_replacement_characters variable will change to True. I then check that and proceed if the answer is False, otherwise I pass that particular souped_page and do not collect the text.

```
souped_page = bs4(request.content,'html.parser')
if souped_page.contains_replacement_characters != False:
    pass
```